# Error in my elastic average query - malformed

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am getting a reason": "[query] query malformed, no start_object after query name" error, not sure why.

The query is meant to grab the difference between two date fields and calculate average of all the results, I believe this should work but it may not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am on elastic version 5.6.12

query below:

```
POST index_my.test/_search
{
  "size":10,
   "query": {
      "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
            "query": 
              "match_all": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
         "filter": {
            "and": [
               {
                  "exists": {
                     "field": "activity.timeline.found"
                  }
               }
               {
                  "exists": {
                     "field": "activity.timeline.sent"
                  }
               }
            ]
         },
         "aggs": {
      "avg_timedifference": {
         "avg": {
            "script" : "Math.ceil(doc['activity.timeline.found'].value - doc['activity.timeline.sent'].value)"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a comma before "filter". Try this:

```
POST index_my.test/_search
{
  "size":10,
   "query": {
      "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
            "query": 
              "match_all": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    },
         "filter": {
            "and": [
               {
                  "exists": {
                     "field": "activity.timeline.found"
                  }
               }
               {
                  "exists": {
                     "field": "activity.timeline.sent"
                  }
               }
            ]
         },
         "aggs": {
      "avg_timedifference": {
         "avg": {
            "script" : "Math.ceil(doc['activity.timeline.found'].value - doc['activity.timeline.sent'].value)"
         }
      }
   }
}
```